# Validation Error in whtml with map value entry

Tags: validation, jsf, selectonemenu

I would like to show the element of the HashMap in a xhtml page (with jsf):

```
  <h:selectOneMenu id="elt" value="#{mgbean.elt}">
                       <c:forEach var="entry" items="#{mgbean.map}">
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}" escape="false" />                            
                       </c:forEach>
     </h:selectOneMenu>
```

the Map is the following:

```
map= new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("1", ">=20");
                map.put("2","<20");
```

I got this error :

> PM org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor execute
>   WARNING: There are some unhandled FacesMessages, this means not every
>   FacesMessage had a chance to be rendered. These unhandled
>   FacesMessages are: 
>   - selectionForm:elt: Validation Error: Value is not valid

i tried to add the following lines but the same error showed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  

<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /></head>
```

how can i fix this error.

UPDATE:

`public String elt;` with getter and setter.

```
public Map<String, String> map;


map= new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("1", ">=20");
            map.put("2", "<20");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should opt for `f:selectItem`, it will take the key as the label and value as.. value:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="elt" value="#{mgbean.elt}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{mgbean.map}"/>                            
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

**Update**

If you want to manually define whether key or value should be the label then try:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="elt" value="#{mgbean.elt}">
     <f:selectItems value="#{mgbean.map.entrySet()}"
         var="entry" itemValue="#{entry.value}" itemLabel="#{entry.key}"/>                            
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

**Also** remember that at any given point in time the value contained in the `mgbean.elt` field must always be one of the keys of your Map. If for some reason you set that value manually to something different that "1" or "2", you might get error as above.

Comment: No, the map variable is as defined a LinKedHashMap. By the way i tried to add the entrySet() and it gave me this error org.apache.myfaces.application.viewstate.ServerSideStateCacheImpl serializeView
SEVERE: Exiting serializeView - Could not serialize state: java.util.HashMap$Entry
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.HashMap$Entry

Comment: try out my updated example

Comment: i got the same first error selectionForm:elt: Validation Error: Value is not valid

Comment: Please add the mgbean code.. especially the 'elt' field

Comment: i updated my post , please have a look

Comment: i have added another update. check it out

Comment: thanks a lot! it worked now with your suggestion:

Comment: Great! Glad I could help